# salt-run command using python api

Tags: python, salt-stack

I am looking a way to find how to call salt-run using python api to list in salt master. Tried to find ways but no help! I want to run this command using python api `salt-run queue.insert myqueue myitem`

Answer (score 5):

This is how you can achieve it:

```
import salt.runner

opts = salt.config.master_config('/etc/salt/master')
runner = salt.runner.RunnerClient(opts)

ret = runner.cmd('queue.insert',['myqueue',{'items':['myitem']}])
```

Comment: @AnimeshJain please don't forget to mark it as answered if this answer is works for you

Comment: i used this and I found that sometimes ret is returning true however the value is actally not getting inserted into the queue. Any idea? `
import salt.runner
opts = salt.config.master_config('/etc/salt/master')
runner = salt.runner.RunnerClient(opts)
ret = runner.cmd('queue.insert',['myqueue',{'items':['myitem']}]) `

this returns True

[root@saltmaster1 animjain]# salt-run queue.list_items testqueue
[root@saltmaster1 animjain]# 

but could not get anything in the queue

Comment: @AnimeshJain I am not able to reproduce the issue, as I have tested it three times before submitting my answer, what is your salt version ? maybe you versions is different than mine or something

Comment: salt 2016.3.2 (Boron)

Also found one strange issue that salt queue is not inserting only numeric values in the queue.